# Command with xkeyval keys from different families

Tags: xkeyval

As I stated in some other questions and on my profile page, I am writing a `problem-solution` package (I know, there are some of them already)

I have used `xkeyval` package and my keys, but now, I want to write a wrapper command for some other `environment` or `command` from a different package (not developped by by me) which itself uses `xkeyval` keys as well, belonging to a different key family.

```
\providecommand{\somewrapper}[1][]{%
   \setkeys{mykeyfamily}{#1}%
   % Some stuff not relevant here, e.g. configuration etc.
   \theothercommand[#1]{other content} % Not written by me...
 }%
```

However, this fails of course, since the wrapper command argument should contain key values specific for `\theothercommand`.

Is mixing possible? Stated alternatively: How to distinguish inside which key value should go to `\theothercommand` and which key is connected to my own package code?

To make it clearer: There is no problem with keys having the some name in both families, because I use a specific naming scheme for my command and/or package keys, so key names from different packages do not collide.

Addendum:

One possibility I have in mind is to use a two or even three argument wrapper command, where the first argument contains keys belonging to key family `FamilyA` and the second argument holds keys from `FamilyB`, but this ist not really appropiate, since I would have to change some other commands on top level and to introduce additional optional arguments as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have found the solution of mixing keys -- it's stated in the manual of the `xkeyval` package, but rather hidden.

```
 \providecommand{\MyCommand}[1][]{%
 \setkeys{FamilyA,FamilyB}{#1}%
 % Other operations
 %
 %
 }% End of \providecommand
```

This requires, that one knows how the key family of the other package is named.

Now the bad news: Since the other package uses `pgf` keys (which do not know of 'families'), this way of mixing keys is rotten.